# How do I test a try-catch?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I was trying out some code in my catch method, and I wanted to try out the exception that it generates.
but in order to reach the catch method, I need to crash my program, so it'll be caught and create an exception.

```
try
{
    //do something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There was an error, please contact the staff");
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\\Crashlog\\Crashfile.txt"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now I wonder, what's an easy, and simple to memorise, line of code that surely makes your program reach that catch method and generate an exception?

Comment: How about `throw`?

Comment: just throw a new exception

Comment: What if `StreamWriter` fails to create/write `Crashfile.txt` file? E.g. if the routine starts from `C:\Program Files\MyRoutine` (usual path to start from) Windows doesn't allow you to create file here (unless you're an admin)

Comment: Do not forget to write down as many data as you can: *Message*, *Stack trace*, *Exception type*

Comment: Think on *dependency injection* - what if you'll want, say, to send a eMail with exception data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
try
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`throw new Exception("Test");` is a reliable way.

You could even include something more useful than `"Test"`.

Comment: What would the "Test" string do if I'll use that?

Comment: You'd be able to inspect the contents of the exception at the `catch` site.

Answer (score 3):

one of the things I like to use in such cases is this:

```
int div = 0;

int res = 3/div;
```

this will throw a [DivideByZeroException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Usually this is something that should not be applied, especially if you are programming on PLC level. But in the C# world it is just an easy mosquito sting.

Comment: I dislike this with a vengeance. Coming from a C and C++ world, this is undefined behaviour. There are better alternatives.

Comment: @Bathsheba that is true ;)

Comment: But I don't think this is incorrect from a C# perspective. Have an upvote!